# How do I migrate my function that needs couple of extra parameters in a new design

Tags: c++

We have an existing class method that accepts two string as parameters:

```
bool myfunc(const std::string& var1, const std::string& var2)
```

The same function is referred across many places. Now I need to modify the same to pass on two more integer parameters:

```
bool myfunc(const std::string& var1, const std::string& var2, int& var3, int& var4)
```

I tried using varadic arguments / function templates but in both case I needed to modify the existing implementation - perhaps I am not sure of the exact implementation. I also wish not using default arguments either - we are using C++11.

Is there a way to create a function template of it that can be called with either two or four arguments passed?

Comment: C++11 has default arguments. Even without them, can't you just overload it?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking about function templates? Can't this be achieved with normal function overloading?

Comment: That would lead to code duplication just the fact that we need to pass extra arguments

Comment: @Programmer you can call one overload from the other, or have both call a separate "implementation" function to avoid code duplication.

Comment: I need to capture the integer values computed with the actual method implementation - so the actual one needs to be modified

Comment: A better title would be "How do I migrate my function that needs couple of extra parameters in a new design?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think templates are overkill here. If you want to have two different valid versions of a function, just make two different valid versions of that function.

```
bool myfunc(const std::string& var1,
            const std::string& var2) {
  // Original implementation
}

bool myfunc(const std::string& var1,
            const std::string& var2,
            int& var3,
            int& var4) {
  // Awesome, cool stuff :)
}
```

If the two do the same thing (presumably with the former pretending it has default arguments, etc.), you could have them delegate.

```
bool myfunc(const std::string& var1,
            const std::string& var2) {
  return myfunc(var1, var2, some_value, some_other_value);
}

bool myfunc(const std::string& var1,
            const std::string& var2,
            int& var3,
            int& var4) {
  // Awesome, cool stuff that works in general :)
}
```

Comment: But I need to pass the two integer variables also to catch the return values from the original implementation and having two functions implementing the same code would lead to code duplication along with extra maintenance

Comment: What's stopping you from delegating from one to the other? If the implementations are different, then of course you have to have both. If they're doing the same work, you should be able to delegate, as I did in the second example.

Comment: I agree but if we implement this way we then would land up in creating more instance of same function based upon arguments to be passed

Comment: So you want to support the old interface for legacy reasons, but you don't want to define a new interface? I'm sorry, but I'm afraid you're losing me. If you want to have two different function signatures then you're going to need two different functions. Even if you hacked it together with templates, you'd still be getting two different functions in the end, as that's what templates do.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Yes function templates would solve but the different implementations would be evaluated at runtime and will have only one implementation - this is where I am failing on how to implement the function template

Comment: Alright, I'm still a bit confused. So you want `myfunc` to have two ways of calling it. Can you explain how it should behave differently if I do `myfunc(a, b)` rather than `myfunc(a, b, c, d)`? Should `c` and `d` be given default values, or what? How will we determine those values in the first case?

Comment: Please let me know how an I create the template such that it can be called both ways - myfunc(a, b) or myfunc(a, b, c, d) and without having default argument values. If in case the same is not possible I would adopt the one you have already stated

Answer (score 0):

I know you do not want to use Default values, however C++11 does support them, and since you do not wish to add multiple signatures I believe this is the simplest solution.

```
static int DEFAULT_VAL = 2;
bool myfunc(const std::string& var1,
            const std::string& var2,
            int& var3=DEFAULT_VAL,
            int& var4=DEFAULT_VAL) {
    // Function implementation
};
```

With these default parameters, you can pass it either 2 or 4 parameters. Both of these examples will work:

```
// Two arguments
myfunc(str1, str2);

// Four arguments
myfunc(str1, str2, int1, int2);
```

You could also check if the integers are equal to DEFAULT_VAL to determine how many parameters were used.

Comment: Thanks - I am trying to avoid using default arguments

Comment: @Programmer Ahh I see you wrote that in your question, I read it too fast